# Homemade Instant Wine Not Fermenting..Can i add yeast on day 3?

Tags: fermentation, primary-fermentation

Hello I am making 3 Day instant beetroot wine. I'm making this in India so I don't have an airlock or a hydrometer or any fancy equipment. I made this wine during last New Year and in 3 days I got an amazing wine that took 1 glass to get An adult drunk. But this time it is not fermenting. it is Day 3 today And there was a large amount of foam at top but no fizzing. I believe its because I added bad yeast. I looked back at the packet of yeast And its 2 months past expiry. Can I add yeast at this point? I can't make a yeast starter because those kind of ingredients are Not Available. I live in a pretty remote area .

UPDATE -

It was that the yeast had gone bad. I added new yeast and now it is fermenting nicely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by  "was a large amount of foam at top but no fizzing" - this sounds like it's fermenting. However you can add more yeast, it will not hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add more yest to a brew at almost any point if you need to. I have added extra yeast(s) to brews up to 4 weeks after filling a FV.

Things to be aware of are:

- usually you will want to make sure the yeast you are adding is in date; unless it is all you have.
- you will want to use a fresh unopened pack, unless you know it has been store in a snitary manner.
- you brew still smells and tatses OK, if the brew has gone bad due to biological contamination, adding more yeast will not help.

So, on day 3 adding extra yeast is absolutley fine.